# how to set up routing for paging in asp.net mvc3 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, paging, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

i have set up simple paging system in my app that is using the idea from nerddinner tutorial, using the paginated list class:

```
   public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>    {
        public int PageIndex {}
        public int PageSize {}
        public int TotalCount {}
        public int TotalPages {}

        public PaginatedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize){}

        public bool HasPreviousPage {}

        public bool HasNextPage {}  }
```

The paging works, and i am using it to get the long tables from the database via LINQ2SQL, as in this controller action:

```
  public ActionResult Index(int page=0)
    {
        const int pageSize = 10;

        var source = repo.SvaMjesta();
        var paginatedList = new PaginatedList<Mjesto>(source, page, pageSize);

        return View(paginatedList);
    }
```

The paging works fine, i can get to any page as long as i am using query type o URL: */Admin/Mjesta?page=2*
That is something i wish to avoid, and would like to use simple URL like: */Admin/Mjesta/Page/2*

To that purpose i have made this entry in my *AdminAreaRegistration.cs*

```
       context.MapRoute(
            "pMjesta",
            "Admin/Mjesta/Page/{page}",
            new {controller = "Mjesta", action = "Index"});
```

But when i try to access URL such as */Admin/Mjesta/Page/2* , it still throws me a 404 error.

My idea was to build some sort of general paging entry in MapRouting at first, so i can use the same partial view to render paging controls with every list where i have such need, but as i couldn't make it work i have tried this more specific approach, but i am still not able to get the controller to react to this URL request.

Any ideas and/or suggestions please?

Comment: Also, if any1 can recommend where to look for a more elegant solution for adding paging and sorting that does not use JS, but uses querystring to hold onto the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have other routes for that area that the url could be matching?

For instance, if you still have the default area route:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "DefaultAreaRoute",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = Url.Optional });
```

and it is listed before your new route, your preferred url will match and use this route first.

Comment: This was the solution for the problem, the default route was actually matching the paging URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
   context.MapRoute(
        "pMjesta",
        "Admin/Mjesta/Page/{page}",
        new {controller = "Mjesta", action = "Index", page = "{page}"});
```